# Couldn't use the MySql.Data.MySqlClient due to version

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2013

I am using VS2013.5, I installed the MySql for visual studio that is in the [MySql Site](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/1.2.html). When I compiled my project, this warning appeared which, in the process, disabled me to use the MySqlClient methods and functions:

> Warning   1   The primary reference "MySql.Data, Version=8.0.12.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d,
>   processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it was built
>   against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" framework. This is a higher
>   version than the currently targeted framework
>   ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5".

how can I resolve this? Is there a way to download and install the older mysql version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use and install an older MySQL connector or a newer .NET version. That is a common problem. Try to install the Version 6.X. Then it could work. If you have downloaded the MySQL integration for the Visual-Studio you have to install an older version. Not all versions are compatible and some new version have bugs and you can't open some windows. I had the same problem.

So you have to try some versions and combinations to find the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you are using .NET Framework v4.5 or v4.5.2, you better use MySQL Connector version 6.9.8. It'll work, mine did.

.NET Framework v4.5.2 work against MySql.Data, Version=8.0.12.0. So you have to use lower version of connector that is compatible with your .NET

Uninstall current connector (8.0.12.0), then from your Project > Reference tab, remove MySql.Data that has a version of 8.0.12.0. Install 6.9.8, then from Reference > Add > Search and CHECK MySql.data 6.9.8.